# problema con el bluethooth socket

Tags: android, arduino

Hola estoy intentando enviar datos desde un movil **android** a un **arduino** a través de un hc-05 cuando realizo el primer envió después de reiniciar el arduino la transmisión funciona correctamente pero las siguientes transmisiones me generan el siguiente log:

> 02-12 20:03:56.676 8370-8915/com.oscar.mandocanarval W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
>   02-12 20:04:01.839 8370-8915/com.oscar.mandocanarval W/System.err: java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
>   02-12 20:04:01.845 8370-8915/com.oscar.mandocanarval W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:741)
>   02-12 20:04:01.845 8370-8915/com.oscar.mandocanarval W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readInt(BluetoothSocket.java:753)
>   02-12 20:04:01.846 8370-8915/com.oscar.mandocanarval W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:375)
>   02-12 20:04:01.847 8370-8915/com.oscar.mandocanarval W/System.err:     at com.oscar.mandocanarval.HiloConexionCliente.run(HiloConexionCliente.java:47)
>   02-12 20:04:20.764 8370-9328/com.oscar.mandocanarval W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback

Mi codigo de envio es el siguiente:

```
public class HiloConexionCliente extends Thread {

UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
String mensaje;
public final BluetoothDevice dispositivo;
public BluetoothSocket socket;
private OutputStream conexionSalida;

public HiloConexionCliente(String direccion, String mensaje){
    this.mensaje=mensaje;
    BluetoothDevice tmpDevice;
    BluetoothSocket tmpSocket=null;
    BluetoothAdapter adaptador = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    adaptador.cancelDiscovery();
    tmpDevice = adaptador.getRemoteDevice(direccion);
    dispositivo = tmpDevice;
    try {
        tmpSocket= dispositivo.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        socket=tmpSocket;
        socket=tmpSocket;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }





}

@Override
public void run() {

    try {
        if(socket!=null){
            socket.connect();
            conexionSalida=socket.getOutputStream();
            conexionSalida.write(mensaje.getBytes());
            close();
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        close();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    super.run();
}

public  void close(){
    try {
        if(socket!=null){
            socket.close();
        }



    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Y el codigo para arduino solamente lee un puerto serie virtual y lo muestra por el monitor serie

Answer (score -1):

Comentas que es un [puerto serial, por lo tanto debe ser suficiente con el ID que estas definiendo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html):

```
UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
```

Pero para evitar el error:

> System.err: java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1

Te sugiero, asegurar que solo tengas un dispositivo emparejado (paired) con el tuyo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.

Comment: Solamente tengo un dispositivo emparejado y sigue sin funcionar si se te ocurre otra cosa agradezco tu ayuda